# How to adjust Arithmetic Coding parameters in integer form?

Tags: compression, h.264, date-arithmetic, entropy, video-compression

### Problem:

I'm using the arithmetic coding model based on [this PDF paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/214762.214771), which is in integer form to realize an unbounded precision.

But the application has some problems: all we calculate is the ***probability*** in `double` form, but the api needs ***frequency count*** in `integer` form, so I made a compromise. I **multiply** the probability by a ***base*** ( near `1e9` ).

```cpp
    double p = calc_prob(i, lap);
    uint64_t f = (uint64_t)( p * base);
```

It leads to a problem: the value of *probability* in double form varies, when the *base* is too small (e.g., `1e9`), smaller values' precision gets lost, but with too big *base* (e.g., `1e10`), the other value **overflow**.

Then I change the *frequency count* from `uint32_t` (4 byte) to `uint64_t` (8 byte), so as to prevent overflow in `uint32_t`, but a new problem occurred:

As the base gets bigger, every frequency count (variant `f` here) becomes larger, too. So the `total` of frequency count has exceeded the model's upper limit (`maximumTotal`)

```cpp
    // Always equal to the sum of 'frequencies'.
    private: std::uint64_t total;
```

```cpp
    // Maximum allowed total from a frequency table at all times during coding.
    protected: std::uint64_t maximumTotal;
```

The probability calculation procedure is irrelevant to this question and can't be released, so I pick up two example values causing problems:

```cpp
    double pMin = 0.000000000913767;//.15lf format
    double pMax = 0.991924503052654;//.15lf format
```

The arithmetic coding model is extracted from [github](https://github.com/nayuki/Reference-arithmetic-coding/tree/master/cpp)

### What I've tried:

I find that the `maximumTotal` is influenced by `numBits` as following

```cpp
ArithmeticCoderBase::ArithmeticCoderBase(int numBits) {
    if (numBits < 1 || numBits > 63)
        throw std::domain_error("State size out of range");
    numStateBits = numBits;
    fullRange = static_cast<decltype(fullRange)>(1) << numStateBits;
    halfRange = fullRange >> 1;  // Non-zero
    quarterRange = halfRange >> 1;  // Can be zero
    minimumRange = quarterRange + 2;  // At least 2
    maximumTotal = std::min(std::numeric_limits<decltype(fullRange)>::max() / fullRange, minimumRange);
    stateMask = fullRange - 1;
    low = 0;
    high = stateMask;
}
```

**numBits resetting**

I've tried to adjust the numBits(default 32), and the maximum becomes 1,073,741,824 as `VC.One` mentioned, but the maximumTotal is still far less than calculated total. From the **pMax** example, it itself exceeds the maximumTotal（multiplied by 1e10）.

My current solution is still using base of 1e9, and assign a smallest probability interval to the coded value. Is there any elegant solution to this?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: **(1)** You need to show testable code instead of images, if you want help to fix your code. **(2)** Isn't your **maximumTotal** at 1,073,741,824 if **numBits** is 32? Was the _"total (frequency count sum)"_ supposed to be larger than 1 billion and why would it be? **(3)** _"The total (frequency count sum) exceeds MaximumTotal"_ Say what you mean!! What is the total count?, what is maximumTotal? How to get your testing numbers?  [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75599307/edit) with testable numbers (and/or code) to recreate your problem.

Comment: I don't know where you are finding the offense. I simply gave you 3 points (or notes) about how to get a fast Answer. Things that get you downvotes are: Not showing code, Keeping technical details mysterious, Lack of own research about issue, Making others have to guess about your input/output etc etc... You had two of those. Also a possible reason that you got a downvote is this line _"**Integer** form to realize an **unbounded precision**"_. Nobody associates Integer with infinite precision, it's why Floats and Doubles were needed in computing (and yet still computers are not good at it).

Comment: PS: It's correct that probability is calculated as a **double** while frequency is an **integer**. No need to multiply by a base. Very simplified... Probability ranges from `0.0 to 1.0`. Now since 1.0 is "full length" you can think of it as 100%, then 0.5 makes the 50% etc. Probability is about where in that 100% space that your symbol is positioned at (_eg:_ 0.75), then frequency count is for how many times the symbol will occur. Example: `aaabbbccc`, (so roughly **a** = 0%-33%, **b** = 33%-66%, **c** = 66%-99%`).

Comment: There is a total of 9 items, so calculate as: `1 / (total_items - 1)` with the minus_one because we count position from zero as first item. We can see that `b` is 4th item and so it has a minus_one position of 3 and it has a **probability** of (0.125 x 3)  == **0.375**, and a **frequency** of (Integer) **3**. All your de-compressing function has to do is: Use the Double to know the position, and then use Integer to know how many times to write the symbol (or item). Create a new result (decoded) from using these two inputs.